# First Application kaa

Tags: kaa

All the things is correctly installed but after I lanched the application, I got these messages :

```
Default sample period: 1 seconds
2017/06/16 9:01:24 [WARNING] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:612] (-7) - Could not find next Bootstrap access point (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2017/06/16 9:01:24 [ERROR] [kaa_tcp_channel.c:307] (-7) - Kaa TCP channel [0xE45F7AB7] error notifying bootstrap manager on access point failure
2017/06/16 9:01:24 [ERROR] [kaa_client.c:240] (-7) - Failed to process OUT event for the client socket 3
Sampled temperature: 30
Sampled temperature: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you forgot to change the Kaa 'host' setting on the Management page of Sandbox (or in Kaa properties file if non-Sandbox version is used).

The error indicates a network problem and needs checking:

1. the Kaa 'host' setting
2. the Kaa SDK used for the application is regenerated after Kaa 'host' change
3. the application is built with the correct Kaa SDK (see item 2)
4. Kaa host IP address is accessible from the PC you are running the application
5. Kaa bootstrap (and other mentioned in documentation) ports are not filtered by any firewall, etc.